# .append python with list of imiona

Tags: python

I am new in python. I trying do some list with name and I don't know where is in here problem

```
>imiona = ["zbychu", "rychu", "zdzisiu"]

>print (imiona)

>imiona[1] = "rychu2"

>print (imiona[1])

>print ((len(imiona))

>imiona.append("Renata")

>print (imiona)
```

and the error showing:

```
imiona.append("Renata")

        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: unbalanced parentheses `print ((len(imiona))` <-- add another `)` to close (3 "`(`" left parens, but only 2 "`)`" right parens)

Answer (score 0):

your line:

```
print ((len(imiona))
```

has three opening parenthesis '`(`' and only two closing '`)`'

Answer (score 0):

Try this, looks like you have missing/extra parenthesis:

```
def main():
    imiona = ["zbychu", "rychu", "zdzisiu"]

    print(imiona)

    imiona[1] = "rychu2"

    print(imiona[1])

    print(len(imiona))

    imiona.append("Renata")

    print (imiona) 

main()
```